# Expect Script expected prompt coming as part of output

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I have an expect script and user prompt is ">" . I create my script expecting ">" to send the next command, but unfortunately, ">" is also coming as part of the output received of the previous sent command, thereby causing my script to send the next command, how shoul I control when ">" coming as prompt and when as part of output?

Comment: The `>` is always at the beginning? You could use anchors (`^`) or lookarounds but please provide some real input strings.

Comment: E.g) Once we login we get something lyk this :-
user@xyz>
And the previous command output is something like this:-
###########################################################################################
>>>>> STARTED (pid)
">>>>>" is at the beginning of line

Comment: Try using `\M>` (mind the backslashes that might require doubling). Or even `\M>\s`.

Comment: Or a more precise: `^[^>]*\M>\s` or `^[^\s>]*\M>\s`

Comment: If I send a cmd, expect will detect the pattern in the output of the previous cmd (as it appears on the terminal) or will read the pattern that appears once the sent command has finished execution and the prompt we have received?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
^\w+@\w+(\.\w+)?>$
```